# how to get SSH server response and status with codes in output file

Tags: vbscript

I need your help. 
I've designed a vbscript using PSFTP.EXE which connects to SSH server and uploads a file. Script creates a command input file and executes every command successfully and generates a log. problem here is that I'm unable to capture sftp server response and status with code. Also I want file transfer status and progress status. below is my script:

```
strHostname = "transfer.com"
   strUsername = "User1"
   strPassword = "password"
   strLocalDir = "C:\data"
   strRemoteDir = "Sales"
   PSFTP_DIR = "c:\windows\"
   PSFTP_EXE = PUTTY_DIR & "psftp.exe"
   strFile1="open.txt"
   strFtpScriptFile = "c:\myscript.txt"
   strOutputFile = "C:\output.txt"
   Set WshShell=CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
   Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set oFile=fso.OpenTextFile(strFtpScriptFile,2,true)
   oFile.WriteLine "lcd " & chr(34) & strLocalDir & chr(34)
   oFile.WriteLine "cd " & chr(34) & strRemoteDir & chr(34)
   oFile.WriteLine "ls" & chr(34)
   oFile.WriteLine "put " & chr(34) & strFile1 & chr(34)
   oFile.WriteLine "bye" & chr(34) & vbCrLf 
   PSFTP = "cmd /c c:\windows\psftp.exe -v -be -bc " & " -l " & strUsername & " -pw " & strPassword &     
   " " & _
   strHostname & " -b " & strFtpScriptFile & " >> " & strOutputFile & " 2>&1"
   Set oScriptExec = WshShell.Exec(PSFTP)
   oScriptExec.StdOut.ReadAll
   WScript.Echo oScriptExec.StdErr.AtEndOfStream
```

Comment: My script is able to download a file from server, but not uploading file from server, also no error prompted or written in log. Exit code is coming as 0. Please help, i'm in urgent need of this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [.ExitCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za76z6hh%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to get "the exit code set by a script or program run using the Exec() method".
2. It makes no sense to re-direct the streams to a file **and** to access them. You need to decide whether you want to parse/analyse/report a log file or to monitor the streams while the .Exec 'works'.
3. Reconsider the trailing quotes after ls and bye.

Comment: I need a status and response of each command that was executed